# What are the alternatives for a multidatabase library for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, database

I want to write an application which should be able to connect to multiple databases (this will be configured by parameters at startup). The application will have different queries for each database engine, this is not a problem.

The problem is that I want to be able to connect to different database engines. Java has JDBC, Perl has DBI. What does C++ have?

What's more I don't want to use database drivers with too strict licences (commercial ones). GPL could be - but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Might be closed down due to the "best" keyword. Consider making it a community wiki.

Comment: SOCI http://soci.sourceforge.net/ - end of discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually every database engine in existence provides an ODBC interface.  I think JDBC is actually a clone of ODBC.

What you want, then, is a C++ wrapper for the ODBC API, that implements RAII to make sure that database resources are released in case of exception, etc. For example: http://simpledb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is the older OLE connections. Using OLE, you could connect to a Flat File, Oracle, SQL, or MySql database provided you have the correct drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC is most compatible and most low-level. OLE DB is higher level and easier to work with, so if you find OLE DB provider for all your possible DB systems, it is the way to go. Otherwise ODBC is your option as virtually all DB systems support it.

EDIT: View this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access.aspx This makes ODBC the only proper choice. :)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ object-relational mapping system **ODB** from the company **Codesynthesis** can be used by GPL version 2 software.

http://codesynthesis.com/products/odb/

Here is a blog entry where they describe why they chose to use native C APIs instead of ODBC to connect to the databases.

http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2011/12/09/oci-mingw/

Speed was one of the reasons.